# TypeScript callback to external file binding "this" keyword

Tags: typescript, this

I have public typescript type like so:

```
export class Generator {

    public generate(settings: GeneratorSettings): void {

        $('#' + settings.Id+ "").dataTable({
            dom: 'RC<"clear">rti<"bottom"pl>',
            sAjaxSource: settings.sourceUrl,
            bServerSide: true,
            pageLength: 15,
            lengthMenu: [15, 25, 50, 100],
            fnDrawCallback: (oSettings) => { this.internalCallback(oSettings); settings.publicCallback(); }
        });
    }

    private internalCallback(oSettings: any) {
        // Do work  
    }
```

In this case I am using a third party library (jQuery DataTables) which provides a callback function. In order to allow users using this type later on to hook into the events, I have included a public `publicCallback` property in my settings which consumers of this type can set to their own function.

One example of the `publicCallback` being used is this:

In a HTML inline script I have:

```
settings.publicCallback = externalModule.initialise;
```

Where `externalModule` is an instance of another TypeScript type as follows:

```
export class ExternalModule {

    public initialise() {

        // Various things happen before here

        $("#button").on("click", (event) => {
            this.buildIdList(event);
        });
    }

    private process(event: any){

       // Doing work

    }
```

My problem lies in the `ExternalModule.initialise` function. As it is being called from the other TypeScript module, the `this` keyword at that point is the `settings` parameter which the `publicCallback` property exists on.

I have read up on the `this` keyword and I understand why that happens, however I can't find a way around it. I have tried doing the following in the `Generator` type:

```
fnDrawCallback: (oSettings) => { this.internalCallback(oSettings); settings.publicCallback.bind(settings.publicCallback)();
```

But this makes is no help as now the `this` keyword points at just the `initialise` method.

Comment: When you have access to the this you need store it in a variable and access that variable

Comment: I never have problem to the `this` context that I want. As soon as the `initialise` function is called, `this` has a context of the `settings` parameter - there is no opportunity to capture the correct context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function like so:

```
settings.publicCallback = externalModule.initialise.bind(externalModule);
```

It will save the scope of `externalModule` as the `this` object, and then your arrow function callback will have the correct `this` as well.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Is there any way you can think of to put this within the `Generator` type to keep the consumption of the callback simple, or is that not possible as far as you know?

Comment: You need the instance of the `externalModule` in order to bind or apply/call on its' `initialise` method, but (as far as I know) you don't have the instance when executing the `Generator.generate` function. You can pass the instance in the settings as well, and then you'll be able to: `settings.publicCallback.bind(settings.publicCallbackThis)` but that will be weird, as you can just pass a bound function to the settings to begin with (as I did in my answer).